# How to show that $f(x):=e^x$ has no absolute minimum?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose for a contradiction, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\delta\leq f(x)$. How can I construct a number $\delta'>0$ such that $e^x=\delta'<\delta$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If $x < \log \delta$ then $e^x < \delta$.

Comment: Your title and body are asking different questions.  It is possible that $f$ has no minimum but nevertheless there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\leq f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The only things we need are obtainable from the definition in power series of exponential.

- $x>0\implies e^x>1$
- $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$

Because from there we can deduce $\forall y>x$ then $\dfrac {e^y}{e^x}=e^{y-x}>1$ so $f\nearrow$ strictly thus cannot have a global minimum.

*Note 1: raptor also uses these two properties in his proof (i.e. $e^d>1$)*

*Note 2: If we try to get monotonicity from $(e^x)'=e^x$ instead of $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$ still from the power series, we are stuck because we don't know $e^x=0$ has no solution (this is somehow what we want to proove) or we are forced to use $e^xe^{-x}=1$ which we wanted to avoid. Thus we don't get the **strict** monotonicity and cannot conclude.*

Comment: This is the key. A strictly increasing function on an open interval (here $\mathbb{R}$) has neither a minimum nor a maximum. +1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it has an absolute minimum at $x_0$, let $x_1<x_0$, and let $d=x_0-x_1>0$. Then

$$e^{x_1}<e^{x_1}e^{d}=e^{x_1+d}=e^{x_1+x_0-x_1}=e^{x_0},$$

which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You have that ${d\over dx}e^x = e^x > 0$ which means that it's strictly increasing. Therefore we can always find a larger value of $e^x$ by picking a larger $x$ and a smaller by selecting a smaller $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the absolute minimum be at $x_0,$ I.e. $y_{min}=e^{x_0}$.

We have:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} e^x = 0$.

$\rightarrow:$

For $\epsilon \gt 0,$  there is  $M \in \mathbb {R}$ such that for $x \lt M$:

$|e^x| \lt \epsilon$.

Choose:

$\epsilon = 1/2(y_{min}) \gt 0.$

$|e^x| \lt \epsilon$.

Contradiction.

Note: $e^x$ is positive everywhere.