# Infinity in multidimensional space

Tags: calculus, infinity

Let's say we have a sequence $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_n} = \infty$. What is infinity here? In other words, if $x_n \rightarrow (a, b)\,(n \rightarrow \infty)$ and $(a,b) = \infty$, then does this mean that $(a,b) = (\infty, \infty)$ or does it mean that at least $a$ or $b$ is equal to $\infty$?

Comment: As noted in Henry's answer, the notation "$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$" has no intrinsic, universal meaning, but must be defined before use, which obviates the question. <> This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4155942/86418) to a related question contains a number of prospective definitions of "$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$", expressed geometrically in terms of the "points at infinity" added to the Cartesian plane.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang hmm okay now I see it. So there must be a missing definition in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it was, say:
$$|x_n|\to\infty$$
this would make sense, but having a 2D value tend to a 1D value is just ambiguous, it could mean any of the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\infty\\\infty\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\infty\\\ne\infty\end{pmatrix}$$
etc